# Should this question be closed?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

I'm wondering why this [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/78588/how-should-i-ask-compensation-for-destroyed-luggage-which-was-primarily-used-to/78597#78597) is closed. The underlying issue is common enough and the chap is asking for assistance but just seems to be getting shot down.

Comment: Well for one the title seems to be enough reason to shoot, but lets not go there. He has to buy a new bag or ask for one from his Company. One way or another he will have to ask his Manager if they do this. In my opinion if they didnt give him one already they will expect him to get his own.